# Interpretation of $f(x)(1 + o(1))$

Tags: notation, asymptotics

What is an exact interpretation of the expression $f(x)(1 + o(1))$?

$o(1)$ - 'o' here is referring to little-oh notation. I understand that any function $g(x)$ with $o(1)$ refers to the fact that function $g(x)$ asymptotically reaches zero, i.e $lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) \to 0$. But when the expression is embedded in such expression above, I am not sure what to make of it.

1. How does $f(x)$ gets distributed to the expression inside? Is it $f(x) + f(x)o(1)$ or something else?
2. What does it really mean when you multiply $o(1)$ to some function? Back to my original question.

Comment: You need to provide context if you want any hope of this getting a useful answer. Where did you come across this expression, what is $f$, …? Please put some effort into your question. Consider reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and then [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4008188/edit) your question to make improvements. As of now, the questions is likely to attract down votes and get closed.

Comment: Do you know what $o(1)$ means?

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for pointing it out. I am new to the forum and learning as I go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I will assume that all the asymptotic notations are at $+ \infty$, and will note e.g. $o(1)$ instead of the more correct $o_{+\infty}(1)$. All what follows holds anyway even when we are not "close to $+\infty$ but close to a specific point $x_0$", but it is simply easier to write and to make proofs.

You can simply think of $o(1)$ as *some* function which converges to $0$. More generally, $o(f)$ can be thought of as a function $g$ such that $\frac g f \to 0$.

You can more formal definitions in the other answers. However, one cool thing is that if you think of them as functions, you get a good intuition for some properties that are effectively true !

For example, if you take two functions $f$ and $g$, then $f \times o(g) = o(fg)$

In your case, you get $f(1+o(1)) = f + o(f)$.

Intuitively, you multiply $f$ by something that is roughly equal to $1$. Hence, the result is $f$ but some error, and the "order of magnitude" of this error has been multiplied by $f$. So to answer your two questions:

1. You can distribute as usual, and whenever you encounter a product of the form $f \times o(g)$, you can slide the $f$ inside the $o$ to get $o(fg)$. This is also why you will never really encounter the notation $f(x)o(1)$, because it is not really practical and does not give more information than $o(f)$. Because we tend to think of $o(f)$ as "error terms", we "add" them to the rest of our equalities.
2. When you multiply $o(1)$ by some function $f$, you are multiplying $f$ by something which tends to $0$. You don't know at which rate, but you know that it goes to $0$ as you get closer to $+\infty$. Hence, the only thing that you know about $f \times o(1)$ is that it is negligible compared to $f$, because it is the product of $f$ and something converging to $0$. This is exactly what the notation $o(f)$ means (and as I already mentioned, it is in fact correct to write $f \times o(1) = o(f)$).

Don't worry, the Landau notations take a while to get used to, but you will eventually get a better grasp on what they really mean and what you are allowed to do with them.

Comment: Thank you! It helped to understand! :)

Answer (score 0):

First the notation only makes sense if you add where the Landau notation $o$ is taken. Assumes that it is at $x_0 \in D$ where $D$ stands for the domain of $f$. Then it means that it exists a map $\epsilon: D \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \epsilon(x)=0$ where $g(x) = f(x)(1 + o(1))$ is equal to

$$g(x) = f(x) (1+\epsilon(x-x_0)).$$

And if you're considering a neighborhood of $\infty$, then you have $g(x) =f(x)(1+\epsilon(x))$ where $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \epsilon(x)=0$.

Comment: I assume you meant to claim something about the limit of $\epsilon$. And probably have $x\to x_0$.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for noticing the typo. Answer updated! Not good to do too many things at the same time...

Comment: $x\to\infty$ would be the usual interpretation here, I would say.

Comment: @TonyK Why do you say so? I may miss something but it seems that Landau notation can be used in a neighborhood of whatever point you. No?

Comment: @TonyK I saw now that the OP updated the question.